# How do I publish a package using NuGet API?

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to publish NuGet packages to internal Nexus NuGet repository using NuGet API in a C# Console application. Code snippet:

```
List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>> providers = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());  
PackageSource packageSource = new PackageSource("http://nexus:8081/nexus/nuget-repo");
SourceRepository sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, providers);
ISettings settings = NuGet.Configuration.Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(@"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet", null, new MachineWideSettings());
var packageSourceProvider = new PackageSourceProvider(settings);
packageSourceProvider.SaveActivePackageSource(packageSource);
                
 
try
{
    await PushRunner.Run(
        settings,
        packageSourceProvider,
        filetouse,
        "http://nexus:8081/nexus/nuget-repo",
        "MY API KEY", "", "", 10, false, true,
        new Logger());
}
catch(Exception e) 
{
}
```

The problem I am getting is that the call to PushRunner completes immediately with no exceptions and the package is not pushed. I see a message in the console that NuGet is going to push the package, but no other logging is emitted after that. I have tried pushing the same package using nuget.exe and it works fine. The Nexus server requires username, password, and API key to publish NuGet artifacts.

NuGet API is lacking documentation so I am not sure what the issue is and whether I am doing this the right way or not.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I would like to pass the username and password in the code somehow. I am presuming the credentials are required (plus API key) as nuget.exe prompted me to enter the credentials. When testing the above code, I saved credentials in the user specific nuget.config.

Answer (score 2):

It has been some time now, but I have successfully just done this by using the NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat NuGet package. This is the package that implements the NuGet part of the dotnet.exe. The way I got it to work in a really easy way was to execute the Program.Main method as you would call the exe itself. The documentation for dotnet nuget push is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push?tabs=netcore21.

So then the code becomes:

```
Program.Main(new[] { "push", packagePath, "-k", apiKey, "-s", serverUrl });
```

You only get a return code back, but currently (in version 4.8.0 of the package), there is another version of Main (MainInternal), where you can intercept and override the logging of the operation as well.

Comment: Great find Ivan. I ended up using nuget.exe as could never get this to work which is a shame.

Comment: For version 5.8.0 and higher `Program.Main()` from `NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat` is not accessible anymore. There is an alternative though, see https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10762.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this in code you can add a credential provider. Here is the code used by nuget.exe push:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f55f41629b0016072dc24f6effcc72e430609b6f/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Commands/Command.cs#L156-L173

Alternatively you can add the credentials to your nuget.config, then read the settings from that file. If you can get nuget.exe push working first with nuget.config so that there are no prompts, then it should easier to load the same settings and run the code you already have.

Comment: I have tried adding credential provider but the callback is not invoked. I prefer passing the username and password rather than relying on nuget.config. In any case, I am still unsure about what Nuget format to use against Nexus 3. Seems Nexus 3 has no Nuget v3 support https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/#!topic/nexus-PackageServerusers/Zd3NOyBpOS8. However, nuget.exe 3.4.x is able to upload to Nexus 2 and Nexus 3. Justin, do you have any working code that I could use? I originally started with Nuget.Core and used PackageServer.PushPackage() but server drops the connection.

Comment: I attempted to copy SetDefaultCredentialProvider() but CredentialService is not available. I simply mimicked "CoreV2.NuGet.HttpClient.DefaultCredentialProvider = new CredentialServiceAdapter(CredentialService);" but did not set HttpHandlerResourceV3. Do I need replicate SetDefaultCredentialProvider() exactly?

Comment: What would be appreciated is some working code as otherwise, it feels I am not making progress and would need to resort to invoking Nuget.exe directly (by first calling 'nuget sources add...' and pass the nuget.config via -ConfigFile to 'nuget push'). I would rather avoid calling nuget.exe directly is possibly.

Comment: Hi Justin, I was looking at https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f55f41629b0016072dc24f6effcc72e430609b6f/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/Program.cs and saw some code to load extensions and catalogs etc. I wonder if I need to do this? My code fails to go anywhere once PushRunner is called - suggesting there might be some underlying Nuget related issues. Thanks Nish